# Error while connecting to spring data with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb, spring-java-config

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on itsadmin.users' on server 127.0.0.1:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on itsadmin.users' on server 127.0.0.1:27017

Here this is my spring-config.xml

```
<mongo:mongo id="myRs" host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="itsadmin"  />


<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    <property name="writeConcern" value="FSYNC_SAFE"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myRs"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="itsadmin"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="mechanism"
        value="#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}" />

    <constructor-arg name="username" value="admin" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you are using has read permissions on your `itsadmin`database. You can see how to do it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#view-a-user-s-roles). If not you can add it like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#grant-a-role)

If yes, it's probably spring not being able to get the credentials. Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454541/query-failed-with-error-code-13-and-error-message-not-authorized-on-db-to-exe), as it seems to be related

Comment: i have already given permissions but still getting same error

Comment: hum have you tried using mongo shell with the given user/password and query the collection? this way you can narrow  the problems

Comment: getting data when using mongo shell

Comment: Then it seems that Spring is not being able to read the credentials correctly. I'll update the answer with an SO link that might help